# Was Tenavik hinting towards a solution to Michael's time navigation problem?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-trek, star-trek-discovery

In *Star Trek: Discovery* S2E12, when Tenavik reads from 'The Pillar of the Present', "***When the future becomes the past, the present will be unlocked***.", was he somehow hinting towards what Michael did later on in the season finale (S2E14) while setting a course for the future through her time suit. She was unable to set a course in the future so she had to first go to the past at the points of the first 5 signals and then she was able to go to the future so that she can save the present. If not, then what was Tenavik's statement's relevance and meaning with respect to the problem that Starfleet was facing?